# Look for specific special characters SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, special-characters

I need to look for mention of below special characters in a description field string/rows.  Some of these are straightforward, but there are some I can't figure out how to look for:

```
Special characters:  < > { } [ ] " ' * = @ ~ | <Tab> (tab key) <Enter> (extra line (carriage return))
```

what I have so far:

```
select * from
table
where [Account description] like '[<>{}[]*=@~|]'
```

Not sure how to identify following special characters:

```
" (double quote)
' (single quote)
<Tab> (tab key) 
<Enter> (extra line (carriage return))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want all non-alphanumeric characters? if so, you can use

```
declare @table table (id int identity (1,1), column1 nvarchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('<'),
('>'),
('{'),
('}'),
('['),
(']'),
('"'),
(''''),
('*'),
('='),
('@'),
('~'),
('|'),
('a' + char(10)),
('b' + char(13)),
('c' + char(9)),
('a'),
('A'),
('1')

select *
from @table
where [Account description] like '%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%'
```

Otherwise, you'll need to list them explicit and use an escape value for the special cases...

```
select * 
from @table 
where column1 like '%[<>{}![!]"''''*=@~|]%' ESCAPE '!'
or column1 like '%' + char(10) + '%'
or column1 like '%' + char(9) + '%'
or column1 like '%' + char(13) + '%'
```

Comment: Why is it that both queries are pulling a, b, and c rows?  Also, what's up with "OR" statements with character length in your second query?

Comment: Because the first is looking for all rows where there is a non-alpha character. In the a, b, and c rows there is non-aplha (tab, CR, etc...). The second query is explicitly looking for each case. If there was another column, say one the special character `:` then the first one would return it but the second one wouldn't. The OR is to handle the conditions of carrige return, tab, etc. char(10) is line feed, char(9) is tab, and char(13) is carrige return in ASCII. see: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Appreciate your in-depth response.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try something like this:

```
select * from table
where [Account description] like '[<>{}[]*=@~|]' 
and [Account description] like '%''%'
and [Account description] like '%'+CAST(X'09' AS TEXT)+'%'
and ([Account description] like '%'+char(13)+'%'
or [Account description] like '%'+char(10)+'%)
```

but I think is gonna be slow.

Comment: that won't work for the brackets and I'd include `%%` otherwise you'll only find columns where *only* that value exists

Comment: @scsimon well i only tried to resolve that for " (double quote)
' (single quote)
<Tab> (tab key) 
<Enter> (extra line (carriage return))

Comment: No worries, I was just making an observation since your have mixed logic.

Comment: I updated my question.  I want to identify special character in description column string.